# Non-parametric z-score for comparison of outliers/extreme values across set of non-normal distributions

Tags: nonparametric, descriptive-statistics, z-statistic

I have a network and for each node in the network I am calculating a certain property, essentially its 'connectedness' to a set of source nodes.  In order to identify nodes which are better connected than nodes *at a similar geometric distance from the source nodes*, I have grouped nodes into shells of given radii from the source nodes.  So for instance, all nodes which lie within 0-2,2-4,4-6,... units of the source nodes.  The following figure shows the distributions of 'connectedness' within the shells.

[image]

I think the best way to describe most of the distributions is that they look roughly straight on a log-log plot (as you can see in the boxed example) i.e. they have wide/long-tails.  Clearly, they are not Gaussian.  Ideally, I would like to calculate a single score for each node, which gives a measure of how 'unexpectedly' well connected it is and is comparable across shells.  I started by using a z-score $\frac{x_i - \bar x}{\sigma}$, but given the distributions are far from normal this doesn't seem like the best measure.  I have switched to a z-score based on the median $\frac{x_i - \text{median}(x)}{\sigma}$, but this still feels unsatisfactory.

Is there some kind of non-parametric measure which could be used to compare the significance of the outliers across shells and obtain a single ranking for all nodes in the network?

Comment: Here you have an answer along your suggestion but swapping the sd from the denominator by the median absolute deviation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/can-we-use-leave-one-out-mean-and-standard-deviation-to-reveal-the-outliers