# Filtering outliers: maintaining consistency over time with newly added records

Tags: outliers

Each item in a table has a price and is assigned to a region. I filter out outliers by identifying and deleting the records whose prices are more than 3 standard deviations away from the average for their own region.

But, in the future I'll be adding new records to the same table. If I apply the same filtering rule to them, the de facto criteria will be different, because average and standard deviation per zone will have changed because of the previously deleted records.

How do I guarantee consistency in this case?

Comment: Setting aside the inter-temporal consistency issue, note that there is a better way to filter outliers, see: [Can we use leave one out mean and standard deviation to reveal the outliers?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/121075/7290)